# How to use a string to find a symbol in a hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash, key

I have a string:

```
category = "cupcakes"
```

I need to see if this hash has that string, converted to a symbol, as a key:

```
products = {
  :cupcakes => [{:title => "chocolate", :flavor => "chocolate"}, {:title => "summer special", :flavor => "pink cake"}],
  :cookies => [{:title => "chocolate bliss", :flavor => "chocolate chip"}, {:title => "breakfast surprise", :flavor => "oatmeal raisin"}]
}
```

This one does not work because category is a string, not a symbol.

```
products.key?(category)
```

This one does not work because `:cupcake` is a unique symbol, and we are just creating another symbol.

```
products.key?(category.to_sym)
```

Comment: Is the category singular or plural?

Comment: _"we are just creating another symbol"_ – no, each symbol `:cupcake` refers to the very same object. It doesn't work because your key is `:cupcakes` (with "s").

Comment: @stefan, I fixed the type-o (plural "s")  I don't have access to the :cupcake, as the user is going to input a string, and I need to use this string to access :cupcake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this comes from a misunderstanding of how symbols work. Every symbol with the same content is absolutely identical down to having the same `object_id`. Symbols with different content are *always* different. This is in contrast to strings where they may have identical content but a different `object_id`, or where one moment a string might contain one thing and the next it's completely different despite having the same `object_id`.

Ruby's `object_id` values are just what they say they are, "object identifiers", and are a way of saying "object number".

Now the string `"cupcake"` and the symbol `:cupcake` are not the same:

```
  "cupcake" == :cupcake
  # => false
```

If you do the conversion, they are:

```
  "cupcake".to_sym == :cupcake
  # => true
```

The real problem is you're expecting `:cupcake` and `:cupcakes` to be the same thing. Ruby doesn't understand English rules and semantics, so as far as its concerned those are two completely different things.

If you're using ActiveSupport you can do things like:

```
"cupcake".pluralize.to_sym == :cupcakes
# => true
```

That requires an additional library, but the good news is it comes with things like Rails by default.

In any case, the way you've defined your data you need to reference it as something like:

```
products[:cupcakes]
products["cupcake".to_sym]
products["cupcake".pluralize.to_sym]
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  I fixed the type-o (a missing s) and now my code works.  Thank you for the clarification about symbols.  A little type-o can cause a beginner to feel lost for quite awhile, so that really helped!

Comment: One of the most perplexing things about Ruby is symbols vs. strings. Glad I could help.